# How to print sql result without executing the sql statement?

Tags: java, sql

I have a SQL statement which will delete certain row according to their ID and area. Can I system.out.println this statement WITHOUT executing the statement itself? I just want to be sure that what I am deleting is correct.

Here is a sample statement:

```
PreparedStatement ps = db.getPreparedStatement("delete from tbl_traininglinks where training_title IN ('"+vwarnid+"')");
    int i=ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: change it to a select query.

Comment: What do you mean without executing the statement? Do you mean your DELETE statement? Then you might use SELECT statement at first hand with the same WHERE clause as your DELETE statement then print the result. In that way, you are not executing your DELETE statement first. But instead, you did execute a SELECT statement before DELETING that specific data.

Comment: seems to be a little bit offtopic, but since you are using prepared statements you could start using the '?' operator to prevent sqlinjections and the like.

   `String updateStatement =
        "delete from tbl_traininglinks where training_title IN (?)";
   PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(updateStatement);
   ps.setInt(1, vwarnid);
   int i = ps.executeUpdate();`

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this question is already answered in the comments but I would like to add something which may be relevant, depending on how your application is used.

If you use `SELECT` and wait for user verification before you use `DELETE`, the data in the table might be changed in the meantime and you can end up deleting rows your didn't get in the `SELECT` statement and that the user did not verify for deletion. This might happen even if you just display the results of the `SELECT` statement and then delete immediately, but the chance is smaller.

Instead, I recommend you use `SELECT` and after the user verifies the deletion build a `DELETE` SQL command that uses the keys of the rows you received in the `SELECT` statement. This way you delete only what the user verified for deletion.

Answer (score -1):

There is a feature called

```
ROLLBACK
```

if you are using transactional database.

Comment: This is true.  Could you elaborate on how one would use it with JDBC?

Comment: I would suggest against it. This would scale extremely poorly when used in bulk, especially compared to the suggestion above (using SELECT instead of DELETE). Having said that, you can start a transaction [this way](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-begin.html),  then end it not by using [COMMIT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-commit.html), but [ROLLBACK](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-rollback.html).